# How can I convert the umask PHP returns to a normal integer format?

Tags: php

When I call `umask()` php returns `18`, what I was expecting was something like, `022`

How can I convert this `18` value to the `022` format?

Comment: It is better practice to use [`fileperms()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) to get the current file permissions and [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to set them.

Comment: are you saying to use `fileperms()` to get the umask?

Comment: umask return old umask value. So your old umask value is set to 18, so you are receiving 18

Comment: @the_velour_fog, Yes. From the [PHP manual for `umask()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php): _Avoid using this function in multithreaded webservers. It is better to change the file permissions with chmod() after creating the file. Using umask() can lead to unexpected behavior of concurrently running scripts and the webserver itself because they all use the same umask._

Comment: @Tigger ah, ok. I was reluctant to have to manually set the file permissions for  every PHP statement that creates a file (because the default umask seems too restrictive) but that explains it well. thanks.